# Will disabling "symlink" in PHP.ini prevent attackers from attacking other websites?

Tags: php, shared-hosting, symlink

I have a small shared server where couple of websites are hosted, so I'm not sure if this kind of protection will be enough to prevent attackers from executing symlink attack.

I've added `symlink` to disabled PHP functions and of course others like exec to prevent from executing `ln` command.

Also `apparmor` is there in order to prevent some kind of damage.

Even if I allow all PHP functions and those dangerous, apparmor will block `ln` command:

```
apparmor="DENIED" operation="exec" profile="/usr/sbin/apache2" name="/bin/ln"
```

Is this sufficient protection against symlink attack?

Comment: I hope you're not asking this because you're setting up [Freedom Hosting 3...](http://securityaffairs.co/wordpress/55990/deep-web/freedom-hosting-ii-hack.html)

Comment: Not even close, and I'm not sure what made you think that I'm setting that kind of server...

Comment: it was meant to be tongue and cheek as Freedom Hosting 2 was compromised by a symlink vuln not more than 2 weeks ago.

Comment: That's strange, probably sftp chroot was not setup, otherwise you can not make symbolic link outside your directory...

Comment: the hackers write-up is available in the linked page from first comment if you're interested

Comment: Yes, I've checked that - 3. login via sftp and create a symlink to / - this was a key of attack, that's why I said that it seems that sftp was misconfigured.

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic links is used for creating shortcuts in Linux.
If an attacker gains access to any single site on your server, he can easily
create a symbolic link to / directory & then putting the document root
afterwards it. Now the attacker can easily read your sensitive files.

**You can protect it by:**

Change the permission of /bin/ln to 400.

Locate php.ini by command- “locate php.ini” (without quotes). Edit the main
php.ini & disable symlink & proc_open.

If you have a shared host, & it is vulnerable to symlink, then change the
permission of your configuration files to 400.

Turn PHP safe_mode ON

Comment: Changing permissions of /bin/ln to 400 is a very weak protection, if the attacker finds some security hole in PHP, they can create symlinks directly via the symlink() syscall.